# Can anyone identify this flowering plant?

Tags: identification

This was taken night so the beautiful yellow flowers don’t show too well. It grew a foot just in the last week! [image]

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Canna indica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canna_indica) or less formally Canna Lily. Mostly they have red flowers but there is a yellow variety as the wiki page shows. The large paddle shaped leaves are distinctive. They grow from a large thick rhizome root; it looks like this one will soon need more room to grow in that pot. They are native to the American tropics and like warm to hot weather, growing quickly when the conditions are warm.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: I will definitely transplant it on its own.