# Plant/flower identification?

Tags: identification, flowers, propagation

Can someone identify this plant?

Also, how does one propagate this plant to a pot?

This plant grows in Florida.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're cannas. This is actually a near-duplicate of [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/47297/can-anyone-identify-this-flowering-plant/47301#47301). Cannas have [very large rhizomes](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.xH6rRFisClEo-IGZrlsYeAHaFP%26pid%3DApi&f=1) which, in the Northern US, are dug every fall, stored over the winter indoors, and then planted out in the spring. You would use this same method in a pot, but make sure that the pot is large enough! I would estimate that a seven-gallon pot is the minimum size to use for a canna.

Comment: Thanks. Dumb question: where is the rhizome located?

Comment: I saw them on the street, so what would I need to transplant them to a pot?

Comment: In Florida ,you can just leave them in the ground. They like water and will even grow in a bog situation  ; they also do well with "average "water .

Comment: @rbhat first, you need a *permission* - it’s probably not a good idea to start digging in someone’s flower bed. The rhizomes are in the soil. Basically thick roots-like storage organs.

Comment: @rbhat - I included the pot information in my answer because it's in the question you asked. As blacksmith37 noted, they can be left in the ground year-round in Florida and other southern US regions.